# executeFetchRequest:error: freezes on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

AFAIK `ManagedObjectContext` must be used in the same thread it was created in, otherwise it might get frozen because of lock.

I have the situation when I get lock when trying to make `executeFetchRequest:error:` in main thread, in which my `ManagedObjectContext` was created in the first place (I can see that call actually appears in main thread because I have a crash report after app was trying to resume from background - "[APPNAME] failed to resume in time").

That's weird. I don't understand what locks my MOC (I can see other threads call trace in previously mentioned crash report and there is nothing like `CoreData` in them) and I would really like to know what could possibly cause this and how can I debug it.

By the way, this situation happens very-very rarely. And after some changes that could possibly solve the problem I don't know the result until it happens again. That's very frustrating.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

UPDATE:

here is some code (though I really doubt it would actually help to understand the issue)

```
- (NSArray *)existingIncomeInvites
{
    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Profile"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"connectionRequestDidReceive = YES"]];

    return [self.dataModel.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
}
```

app freezes here on last line

here are some other pieces of code

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        LOG(@"Trying to get MOC on main thread!");
    }

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)showBadgeOnButton
{
    NSArray *incomeInvites = [self.dataModel.profileManager existingIncomeInvites];

    ...
}
```

and `showBadgeOnButton` is called from my `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

what I recently changed is this - @"connectionRequestDidReceive = YES" previously was @"connectionRequestDidReceive == YES", but I don't think that should make any difference...

Comment: Can we see some code ? Where are you calling it ?

Comment: Sure, but im trying to see where you call executeFetchRequest:error: as if this is at a point where the UI isn't loaded for instance it will cause a hang.

Comment: @Dev2rights, what do you mean "UI isn't loaded"? As I mentioned in my update, all this call stack is called from `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`, so I guess everything's loaded at this point.

Comment: If you are getting "failed to resume in time", it is normally because your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is taking too long to return.

Comment: @Michael, yes, I know that. I want to know WHY CoreData causes such a problem.

Comment: Interesting... There is no answer neither for my question nor for similar ones. Quite a mystery I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.
Apparently I was using persistentStoreCoordinator in a very not obvious way - accessing data in faults. I didn't even know that my managedObjects were in fact faults. And I did that access in a background thread. So that was the thing that caused me so much pain.

Hope that would help somebody.